# Override Scrapy logging esp. from middleware

Tags: logging, scrapy, robots.txt, scrapy-middleware

I have used Scrapy in a project where I have my own JSON logging format.

I want to avoid any multi-line stacktraces from Scrapy especially from middlewares like the one for `robots.txt`. I would prefer it to be a proper one line error or the entire stacktrace bundled up into a message.

How can I disable or override this logging behavior? Following is one sample stacktrace I got from a download middleware for `robots.txt`

```
2017-10-03 19:08:57 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.example.com/robots.txt>: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.example.com. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/auser/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)   File "/Users/auser/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)   File "/Users/auser/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))   File "/Users/auser/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "/Users/auser/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 954, in startConnectionAttempts
    "no results for hostname lookup: {}".format(self._hostStr) twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.example.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why don't like error message to be multiple lines (it is the print of traceback of the exception). Anyway, we could custom the formatting of Scrapy logging. Assuming that you were running your crawling scripts by `scrapy` command line, e.g., `scrapy crawl` or `scrapy runspider`. Here is a sample code (python 3 version) that shows how to use your own formatter.

```py
    import logging
    import scrapy
    
    
    class OneLineFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(OneLineFormatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        def format(self, record):
            formatted = super(OneLineFormatter, self).format(record)
            return formatted.replace('\n', ' ')
    
    
    class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "test"
        start_urls = [
            'http://www.somenxdomain.com/robots.txt',
        ]
    
        def __init__(self, fmt, datefmt, *args, **kwargs):
            my_formatter = OneLineFormatter(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
            root = logging.getLogger()
            for h in root.handlers:
                h.setFormatter(my_formatter)
            super(TestSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        @classmethod
        def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
            settings = crawler.settings
            return cls(settings.get('LOG_FORMAT'), settings.get('LOG_DATEFORMAT'))
    
        def parse(self, response):
            pass
```

And the following are some explanations.

1. Python logging working flow. The `scrapy` itself uses python built-in logging system. Thus you need some basic knowledge of python logging, especially the relationships among `Logger`, `Handler`, `Filter` and `Formatter` classes. I highly suggest the [working flow](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) of python logging.
2. Scrapy logging and settings. If your spider is run by `scrapy` command line, e.g., `scrapy crawl` or `scrapy runspider`, then the Scrapy function `[configure_logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow)` is called to initialize logging. The instruction of [scrapy logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) could give some instruction of how to custom your logging and by [scrapy settings](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#how-to-access-settings) you could access your settings.
3. How the sample code works. The basic working flow is:

- First, you need to define your own formatter class to custom the logging formatting.
- Second, in your spider, you need to get access to your formatting settings to initialize your formatter class.
- And finally, in your spider, you get the `root` logger and set your formatter to all handlers of `root`.

If you write your own script and use Scrapy as API, see [run Scrapy from a script] (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), then you need to configure the logging your self.

The above formatter will not work until the spider is initialized. Here are some prints:

```bash
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
    ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
     'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
     'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: []
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.somenxdomain.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.somenxdomain.com.
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.somenxdomain.com/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.somenxdomain.com.
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.somenxdomain.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.somenxdomain.com.
    2017-10-03 11:59:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.somenxdomain.com/robots.txt> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks     result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)   File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator     return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)   File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request     defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))   File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 954, in startConnectionAttempts     "no results for hostname lookup: {}".format(self._hostStr) twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.somenxdomain.com.
    2017-10-03 11:59:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
    2017-10-03 11:59:40 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats: {'downloader/exception_count': 3,  'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 3,  'downloader/request_bytes': 684,  'downloader/request_count': 3,  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,  'finish_reason': 'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 3, 15, 59, 40, 46636),  'log_count/DEBUG': 4,  'log_count/ERROR': 1,  'log_count/INFO': 7,  'scheduler/dequeued': 3,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,  'scheduler/enqueued': 3,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 3, 15, 59, 39, 793795)}
    2017-10-03 11:59:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

You could see that after the running of spider, all messages are formatter into one line. (By removing `'\n'`).

Comment: super thanks. I have upvoted the answer but will accept it once I am done using the solution.